# Amazon EC2 Linux PHP slowing down after each deployment

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, system-administration

I have an EC2 server running a Laravel application, driven by RDS MySql database. Each time I deploy the application it works fine, but after about 1 week of use it becomes progressively slower, until the eventually the site won't load at all (for any visitor) and 502 errors result. One I re-deploy the application (thus rebooting the server) it works fine, then begins to slow down again.

What could be POSSIBLE causes of a steady drain on resources for such an application? Having tried Cloudwatch and server logs, I cannot find any resource which is close to its limit, but the behavior persists. (CPU, CPU credits, Burst, Memory etc...)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible this cannot be found unless your application logs something, you have to look into CPU load , Disk , Memory free etc etc to figure out

Comment: what are some possible causes? Its not CPU, disk or free memory...

Comment: Why would it get slower over time? It is a cumulative effect

Comment: did you checked on the network ? Ex: there are too many open connections to RDS and slow-queries stuck,  so your EC2 instance keeps waiting .. so it might be a case on RDS side as well

Comment: check active connection in RDS as well, if that is also going up, that means your application is creating a lot DB connections, which causes the whole application to  slows down.

Comment: Checked RDS connections, they don't seem to be increasing, just the few connections I would expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 502 error is suggesting issue with communication between web server and the app handler - most probably being caused by your instance running out of memory due to it being a micro (guess).  In this case I also assume you are using PHP-FPM.

Try restarting just PHP-FPM and see if your site becomes responsive again.  This will tell you your issue is most likely occurring at the application layer.

Tail Web Server error logs - you should have some indication of what is causing the issue here and if you are unsure post.

If your app doesn't respond to web server in the allotted time this will also cause an issue - check your PHP.ini for the following param:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

If using Nginx you will also need to modify config to increase the timeout here also.  Look for the following param:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
```

You will probably want to create a swap file after you have done this.  It's either this or increase your instance size.  Your issue is really not likely RDS or a network issue (obviously) due to infrastructure you are running your app on.

> OPS note 
>   I checked the error logs using the following method : https://www.bigappledesigns.com/2013/06/how-to-access-apache-web-server-httpd-error-logs-for-amazon-ec2-linux-and-most-other-linux-varieties-also/ 
>   This revealed several "out of memory" messages.

Comment: Thanks for this advice! I have checked the logs, which show that the server is running out of memory! If I upgrade the instance will this keep happening, as it seems to increase over time?

Comment: You're welcome.  Probably not but it depends on what size instance you require and also on your entire stack - e.g. versions of PHP / Framework etc.  The quickest solution would be to increase instance size.  The thing is it doesn't guarantee a fix.  You should definitely create a swap file first.  It's an easy fix and then you can increase instance size when you really need to.

Comment: swap file added, thanks for the extra advice! I hope that stabilises it

Comment: No problem, you can still always bump to a higher instance if you need to.

Comment: That swap file is working great, and really easy to set up or add to elastic beanstalk. Now that the server doesn't "crash" I can see that certain tasks use all the memory, like the build, but 99% of the time we have enough memory.

Comment: That's great to hear!